# How to pass a dataframe and uneven vectors as parameters in purrr map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a function with mixed data types. It takes a data frame and string variable as the input parameter.

```r
library(dplyr)


myfunc <- function (dat=NULL,species=NULL,sepal_thres=NULL) {
 dat %>% 
    filter(Species==species & Sepal.Length <= sepal_thres) 

}

myfunc(dat=iris,species="virginica",sepal_thres=5)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 1          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica
```

But I want to apply it with list of vectors

```r
species_vecs <- c("virginica","setosa")
sepal_thres_vecs <- c(5, 6)
purrr::pmap(list(dat=iris, species=species_vecs, sepal_thres=sepal_thres_vecs), myfunc)
```

I got this error:

```r
Error: Element 2 has length 2, not 1 or 5.
```

What's the right way to do it?

Not that the `species` and `sepal_tres` parameters are taken from this combination:

```r
 > expand.grid(species_vecs,sepal_thres_vecs) %>% rename(species=Var1, sepal_thres=Var2)
    species sepal_thres
1 virginica           5
2    setosa           5
3 virginica           6
4    setosa           6
```

but `dat` as parameter is fixed.

Answer (score 6):

`pmap` will use recycling if you have a length-1 element as part of your bigger list.  In this case, you can pass `iris` as a list element within the full list to use it for each species-sepal combination.

Note that `pmap` goes through list elements with multiple values in the order they appear.  If you want every combination of the species and sepal vectors in `pmap` you would need to create and give the full vectors as list elements (i.e., you would have to do the crossing yourself).

```
purrr::pmap(list(dat = list(iris), species = rep(species_vecs, 2), 
                 sepal_thres = rep(sepal_thres_vecs, each = 2) ), myfunc)

[[1]]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica

[[2]]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
3           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
4           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
5           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
6           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution :

```
expand.grid(species_vecs,sepal_thres_vecs) %>% 
  rename(species=Var1, sepal_thres=Var2) %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(sum = map2(as.character(species), sepal_thres,myfunc,dat = iris)) %>% 
  unnest(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Vectorize`

```
input <- expand.grid(species_vecs,sepal_thres_vecs,stringsAsFactors = F) %>% rename(species=Var1, sepal_thres=Var2)
#     species sepal_thres
# 1 virginica           5
# 2    setosa           5
# 3 virginica           6
# 4    setosa           6
output <- Vectorize(myfunc,c("species","sepal_thres"),SIMPLIFY=F)(dat=iris,species=input[[1]],sepal_thres=input[[2]])
output[[1]]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica
output[[3]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
# 2          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica
# 3          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0 virginica
# 4          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4 virginica
# 5          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5 virginica
# 6          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0 virginica
# 7          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8 virginica
# 8          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
# 9          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```